# repository of available rails engines

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a repository where you can find all the available rails engines?
something like the appstore for rails engines?

I have seen some references to http://rails-engines.org/ but that has only 2 or 3 engines.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not exclusively for rails engines, but [Ruby Toolbox](http://ruby-toolbox.com/) is a good repository of various tools.